# What would be the best SE site for generic 'web/Internet' questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've got a question that is 'purely internet'-centered. It's this:

**'How to get a direct image html path from from a URL with no extension?'**

(with an example in the question being: https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain=nbc.com&feature=youtube_channel)

I don't feel it's suitable for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), because it's not specific to a particular web app - it's a 100% generic question that could apply to *any* web service or website - it's an *Internet* question.

I'm (initially) thinking it's not ideal for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) either, because it's a fundamentally platform-independent 'web' question and I like to think that Super User is more focused more on *computer* use (Windows being its stronghold), than *Internet* use. (Though, due to its sheer force of user-base, I understand it might be a success there anyway.)

I don't feel it's right for [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), because this is from the perspective of the *user*, not the webmaster (though it might still seem a good place all the same since that group would be most knowledgable, if any, on just how this webserver-y type matter works after all) - and it certainly doesn't have anything (directly) to do with [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), nor is it a right fit for the more specialised [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) either.

This is not the first time I've had a 'generic web/Internet question', and no site to ask it on without at least some sense of awkwardness to it. What would be the best place currently for questions like my example, and is there or have there been any 'Web User' site proposals in Area 51 that I haven't noticed? I have not seen one before and am thinking it would be becoming to fill this awkward-seeming gap.

But maybe I'm wrong: given that Super User really is a broad site for 'computer usage', and 'web usage' is indeed a typically central part of this, is Super User the one for generic web questions after all?

Comment: Favicons are kind of a unique scenario. It is possible there is no path to this image with an extension because the `.png` (that is its type) is so small that it is probably stored in a database to be read out in bytes (699 to be precise). Favicons also have an interesting history. Which site all of that fits into? I am not sure either.

Comment: What do you mean by *get a direct image html path*? Do you want to download the image locally? Or use this image in a HTML page? Can you be more precise with your question? It's too short to fully understand your problem, and see which site is best suited for it.

Comment: Hi n.1, firstly it's mostly just an example to illustrate the more important meta issue now, but yes it was the question I wanted to ask (and still would like to), once it's decided what is indeed the best site for it. I think it's Super User indeed, started to realise it when finishing up the question, as I say there...I still will let it sit though, but anyway my example asks 'how to obtain the direct url' as in the public_html web server url path with file extension. (So, http://example.com/path/images/image.jpg, not https://example.com/path/imagephpfunctionthingie?dbentry=1782.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)? It is the more general software question SE site.

Even though you are right [WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) isn't a perfect fit, SEO is on-topic there, so maybe ask in the chat whether they find this related enough.