# What is the right SE site to ask about file conversion specifications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What is the right SE site to ask this question of mine?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627843/what-are-the-constraints-if-any-on-file-conversion-specifications

I asked this on Stack Overflow, but seeing that there has been no response (comment or answer) for more than 2 days, which is unusual in my experience with SE, I surmise that it might be because I've posted it on the wrong site.

Comment: I just found that there is an old question (from 2010) on almost the same lines as my original question on SO: "Reducing the file size of a very large images, without changing the image dimensions" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257322/reducing-the-file-size-of-a-very-large-images-without-changing-the-image-dimens

Answer (score 3):

I would say none. Your question is quite broad and sounds like a tool recommendation. Therefore it doesn't seem an appropriate question to ask here.

You posted it on StackOverflow now. That doesn't seem to be the right choice for sure, since the question doesn't seem programming related.

Comment: Suppose I delete the tool recommendation part and retain the broader conversion question? Is there no site which fits even remotely? Sad, I used to read too much into "For almost every topic worthy of discussion, there is an SE site dealing with it.." :(

Comment: No. Discussions are off-topic. It is simply a question and answers. For discussions, use discussion forums. Here we expect clear, well written questions that have a objective answer. Discussions tend to get opinionate.

Comment: Then the word is probably something other than discussion. That statement is from somewhere on our site, I think you must remember it. (But don't we have a tag 'discussion'?) By the way, can you recommend some discussion forum for this?

Comment: No. And meta is the exception on the rule as it comes to discussions.

Comment: OK. What about SuperUser? This question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231525/what-would-be-the-best-se-site-for-generic-web-internet-questions?rq=1 about generic web/internet questions has an answer recommending it. Will it do good to just try?

Comment: That is my answer actually. That question is very specific, and it is on-topic on SU, but not SO for example (with some modifications it does, just like yours).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is totally on topic for Stack Overflow *if there is a programming component to it*. You are confused about the difference between DPI, PPI and file size of images and how to balance the three factors as part of an upload process - and that is certainly on topic. It can be a broad subject, but if you tighten your question up a little you should be fine.

If your question is more about how to achieve the best scan using certain software then [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the place for it.

Comment: Thank you, is removing the tool recommendation part sufficient? (I should add that that part is not trivial, as extensive google search did not help.)

Comment: @NUnnikrishnan You can ask questions about *how* to do it, but it's advisable to stay away from requesting the names of libraries - that sort of thing is technically off topic (even though it can be hard to find these things out otherwise) and it also acts as a catalyst for people closing the question. If it is a question relating to programming then be specific about what you've tried, what hasn't worked, or where you are stuck. Read up on DPI & PPI first so you know the difference.

Comment: Thank you, but after reading up a bit, I can't see how DPI is relevant to my issue. I realised that more pixels does not necessarily mean greater file size, though. Still, isn't the question as to "what are all the constraints?" a valid one?